# How to retrieve transactions' info such as gaslimit and gasprice from Etherscan?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, etherscan

This link shows the latest 500k transactions, and by clicking each one it opens a page with its info including gaslimit, gasprice, usedgas etc.

https://etherscan.io/txs

How can i retrieve the information for all the 500k in an automatic way, because it is tedious and not practical to do so manually.

Comment: Etherscan offers a proxy API to the underlying node. The tx receipt will give you the info you listed: https://etherscan.io/apis#proxy

Comment: Note that the API is rate limited to 5 requests/second. If you genuinely need the details of all 500k transactions then it'll take you nearly 28 hours of hammering their API... (That's after you somehow get a list of the transactions to feed into the API.)

Comment: Thanks for your replay; not realy understand how it works e.g., could you show an example to retrieve the first 1k transactions? I would appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API from etherscan do not have methods to get a list of the last N transactions. The solution is to download the blocks (with the transactions) and read the data from them.

Assuming an average of 250 transactions per block (source: https://bitinfocharts.com/ethereum/) having 5 requests per second, you will get the data in a couple of hours.

This can be easily done with python and you can use these tools:

https://github.com/corpetty/py-etherscan-api

or

https://github.com/jfdelgad/etherscanAPI
in this last one you can just do:

from etherscanAPI import etherscan

```
apikey = 'yourAPIkey'
myapi = etherscan(apikey, 'mainnet')

currentblock = myapi.getBlockNumber()
txlist = []
i = 0
txcount = 0;
while txcount < 1000:
    block = myapi.getBlockByNumber(int(currentblock,16)-i)
    txlist.append(block['transactions'])
    txcount = txcount + len(block['transactions'])
    i = i + 1
    print(txcount)

txlist = [i for sublist in txlist for i in sublist]
```

then `txlist` will be a list of dictionaries containing all the data of last (>) 1000 transactions.

for instance, txlis[0] will have a dictionary:

```
{'blockHash': '0x60265fe6cffcbd2dc5f3872c4eb151e17919296270210985df3ef2249d99171c',
 'blockNumber': '0x63973b',
 'from': '0x5e032243d507c743b061ef021e2ec7fcc6d3ab89',
 'gas': '0xafc8',
 'gasPrice': '0xcce416600',
 'hash': '0x940cdd338b4ec8f9b2b63c01a88683f8658f9a388d79873c6bb913b34e579dd8',
 'input': '0x',
 'nonce': '0x193dd',
 'r': '0xcffe406e06ac7f5049798785d1ead4d9420aa763838592e275b997d6efb411d7',
 's': '0x5db6e46eae1dae407b4e54c49e50ccb17a41a6569cb848aae021f06d4d7fb450',
 'to': '0xf67fa6500b490a05c29a47b40a9e3b72e3044a15',
 'transactionIndex': '0x0',
 'v': '0x26',
 'value': '0x4563918244f40000'}
```

and you can get the parameters doing for instance: txlist[0]['gas']

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! i got error TypeError: getBlockNumber() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. Also, what attributes does txlist have that i can print out?

Comment: You are right, I updated the code to correct the bug, I run it and it works now. Also the list have dictionaries, so to get for instance the `gas` of the transaction `i` in the list can be obtained with `txlist[i]['gas']`

Comment: Hi Jaime.. I am wondering why api do not print "gas used by transaction" such as in here https://etherscan.io/tx/0x45e0c444b8291060242bf169c1ed6b748e8ea92530f1d18e85b626b51d0974a8?

Comment: This is because the code is reading the transactions and (if I am not wrong) the value of actually used gas is available in the receipt of the transaction. You can use the api method called `myapi.getTransactionReceipt(txhash)` where txhash is the hash of the transaction, then you will get the receipt that contains the the used gas value.

Comment: following to this,, How can I decode transaction input to know what method was called and what arguments were passed in (and arguments types)?

Comment: I think you should make a new question. Let me know and I will try to answer it. Writing code in the comments is not easy.

Comment: please, see my question here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68225/how-can-i-decode-transaction-input-to-know-what-method-was-called-and-what-argum . Thanks